# ::operator new(sizeof(A));, how it works

Tags: c++

I think that it allocate memory of `sizeof(A)` and `return` address to `pointer a`, Am I right?
The second issue is, that I don't understand this `::operator` Why does it use the symbol `::` and the word `operator`?

```
A* a = ::operator new(sizeof(A));
```

Comment: It is supposed to use _global_ new operator, rather than specialized/overloaded version of that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are right, `operator new()` (function) is different from `new` (keyword), that it only allocates N bytes and do not perform initialization of objects. However, the `new` keyword uses `operator new()` under the hood to allocate memory.

Unlike other (standart) functions, `operator new()` is not part of the `std` namespace, but is located in the global namespace. Thus the `::` in front forces the compiler to take the global definition and not a more specialized one. E.g:

```
namespace foo {

    void* operator new (std::size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "custom implementation" << std::endl;
        // some code...
    }

    void SomeFunc()
    {
         operator new(0);   // prints "custom implementation"
         ::operator new(0); // prints nothing at all
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all this *doesn't* work -- when you compile it you get an error like

```
t.cpp:2:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘A*’ [-fpermissive]
 A* a = ::operator new(sizeof(A));
                                ^
```

For what it means, this calls the function `operator new` in the global scope.  The normal global `operator new` allocates the specified amount of memory and returns a `void *` pointer to it (which is why you get the error).

Importantly, this is *not* a `new` expression -- it's just a function call that calls the function normally used to allocate memory for `new` expressions.  It does not call any initializer to initialize the memory in any way.  Which is another reason its an error.

Comment: I think it's valid if `A` is POD?

Comment: No, it is not. At least not in g++ 4.7.3. I imagine all the compilers will treat is as an error.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No an implicit cast from `void*` to another pointer type is only valid in C, but not in C++

Comment: /facepalm, I'm referring to Chris Dodd's last paragraph. Assuming a cast is added to OP's code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well in this case: Casting to `A*` and storing such a pointer are totally legit, however accessing it will result in UB. You might be right though, that this possible does not apply to POD types.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `::` is known as the `scope resolution operator`. In C/C++ every identifier has a scope outside of which it does not exist. Identifiers by default exist in the global namespace unless they are a member of functions, classes or namespaces, where they exist as local identifiers. Symbols/Variables/Identifiers declared in the global namespace use the `::` operator.

Therefore,you have to use the unary scope operator(::) to access an identifier declared within the global namespace, as it can be *hidden* because of an explicit declaration of another identifier having the same name as its own in a block or class. For-example:

```
    int random_number = 0;

    int main(void)
    {
      int random_number = 0;
      ::random_number = 1;  // set global random_number to 1
      random_number = 2;    // set local random_number to 2
      return 0;
    }
```

The declaration of `random_number` declared inside the `main()` function hides the integer named `random_number` declared in global namespace scope(above the main function). 
By using the unary scope operator like `::random_number` we can access the variable declared in the global namespace inside the `main()` function.

**2)** `operator new()` denotes a function whose declaration is as `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );` meaning that it allocates memory/storage of `count` bytes.  If there is insufficient memory for the allocation request, `operator new()` returns `NULL` or throws an `exception`